# ¿Como puedo obtener un texto dentro de un Value con Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy intentando realizar WebScrapy con Python + Selenium, pero necesito iniciar sesión el problema surge al momento de colocar un texto aleatorio dentro de un input ya que no logro obtener el texto de la manera convencional

```
code_auten = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="check_code"]').text
```

Únicamente me esta cargando un espacio en blanco supongo que esto surge porque lo que quiero extraer esta dentro de un **value**, pero no se como extraerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la manera de poder extraer el texto esto lo realice de la siguiente manera:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_id("check_code").get_attribute("value")
```

Esto se puede explicar de la siguiente manera:

1. `driver.find_element_by_id("check_code")` en esta parte buscamos la ubicación donde esta lo que deseamos extraer y en este caso lo estoy buscando por su ID que es `check_code`
2. `get_attribute("value")` aquí estoy obteniendo lo que hay dentro del atributo que deseo que en este caso es un `value`.

No se si este bien explicado, pero me funciono.